# Getting root details from pom.xml file through shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am having one POM.xml file which is having details like "artifactId" & "version" currently I am trying to pull those details from pom.xml through Shell script.

NOTE: I dont want to print "version" and "artifactID" from dependencies block.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  

 <groupId>com.javatpoint.application1</groupId>  
 <artifactId>my-application1</artifactId>  
 <version>1.0</version>  
 <packaging>jar</packaging>  

 <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>  
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  

 <dependencies>  
  <dependency>  
   <groupId>junit</groupId>  
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
   <version>4.8.2</version>  
   <scope>test</scope>  
  </dependency>  
 </dependencies>  

 </project>
```

I tried through grep but no luck :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing `xpath`, which can be installed via `yum install perl-XML-XPath`. Since `xpath` is an xml parser, you can have more confidence that you are getting the correct piece of xml vs a regular expression based solution.

Here is an example with your file:

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_xpath_value {
    xml=$1
    path=$2
    if [ -f $xml ]; then
        # xpath returns <foo>value</foo>, so we need to unpack it
        value=$( xpath $xml $path 2>/dev/null | perl -pe 's/^.+?\>//; s/\<.+?$//;' )
        echo -n $value
    else
        echo 'Invalid xml file "$xml"!'
        exit 1;
    fi
}

pom_xml='foo.xml'

artifactId=$( get_xpath_value $pom_xml 'project/artifactId' )
version=$(    get_xpath_value $pom_xml 'project/version'    )

echo "ArtifactId is $artifactId"
echo "Version is $version"
```

**Output**

```
ArtifactId is my-application1
Version is 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

what format do you want?

```
awk -F '>|<' '/version|artifactId/ {print $3}'file
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zxy. but its showing 

my-application1
1.0
junit
4.8.2


its printing junit & 4.8.2 from dependencies block also.

Answer (score 0):

this helps ? if you have more dependices block, then we have to reset the flag value

```
bash-3.2$ awk '/depend/{flag=1}flag&&/artifactId|version/{next}1' test.txt
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.javatpoint.application1</groupId>
 <artifactId>my-application1</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '<[^>]*>'  '/<dependencies>/,/<\/dependencies>/{next} /artifactId/{$1=$1;print "Artifact IF is:" $0} /version/ {$1=$1;print "Version is:" $0}' input.xml
Artifact IF is:  my-application1
Version is:  1.0
```

*Above code , first ignores the text between `dependencies` block. After that it search for `artifactid` and print its value. Similarly for Version. Field separator is defined to take care of `xml` tags.*